# Generate PDF from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation

The [Ruby On Rails Wiki lists a couple of librarie](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoGeneratePDFs)s that facilitate **PDF** generation in **Rails**. I need to print out address labels (in letter format, thus 12-15 addresses per page) and cannot decide which one to use. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm on formatting holy crusade today :)

Comment: Perhaps you were looking to generate PDFs, not "PFD"s

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The best I've seen so far is Prawn:

- Prawn http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/
- http://advent2008.hackruby.com/past/2008/12/17/awn_and_the_future_of_ruby_pdf_generation/
- http://railstips.org/2008/10/14/how-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-with-prawn
- Prawn Rails plugin: http://www.cracklabs.com/prawnto

Comment: thx! Prawn seems to be the way to go....especially with the prawnto plugin it's really easy to use

Answer (score 9):

Prawn with Prawnto for sure.
The DSL is a real treat, as is the simplicity of being able to treat PDF as any other format in a respond_to format block:

```
respond_to do |format|
format.pdf { render :layout => false }
```

There's a tutorial video on Prawn [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn):

Comment: Looks like the link in this answer broke .. is there somewhere else the information can be found, @btw?

Comment: The link worked for me, but there's an 'updated' (compared to the link posted in the answer, though it's 10 years old now) RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised

Comment: Better yet, the repo: https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails

Answer (score 3):

There's also [RTeX](http://rtex.rubyforge.org/).  That works well if you're willing to translate to [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) first.  LaTeX is a very good way to store marked-up documents.  It just depends on how static each document is.  If most of the document is dynamic, you might do better with Prawn or PDF::Writer.  If most of it is static, with just a couple of text-replacements for each, LaTeX might be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Prawn is the way to go. Now with prawn-labels that is really easy to do.

Check out the project's README here:

https://github.com/jordanbyron/prawn-labels#readme

This is a super simple example being used in a Rails controller. Don't forget to add `gem 'prawn-labels'` to your Gemfile.

```
names = %w{Jordan Kelly Greg Bob}

labels = Prawn::Labels.render(names, :type => "Avery5160") do |pdf, name|
  pdf.text name
end

send_data labels, :filename => "names.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not doing anything too complex, You could also use HTMLDOC, which converts basic HTML to PDF. This prevents you from having to learn more proprietary layout syntax(like in the case of Prawn). It might save you some headaches :)

Here's a link to the ruby gem for HTMLDOC:

- http://htmldoc.rubyforge.org/

Also, here's a good guide for rendering a view in rails to pdf using HTMLDOC:

- http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2007/11/20/easy-pdf-generation-with-ruby-rails-and-htmldoc/

Answer (score 2):

There is also [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit). It's quite interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both PDF::Writer and Prawn and find Prawn much more pleasant to use. Check out [Ruby Mendicant](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2008/03/the_ruby_mendicant_project.html) for a [comparison](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2008/07/ruby_mendicant_permian_prawn.html) that demonstrates the joys of Prawn w/r/t PDF::Writer.

Actually, just check out Ruby Mendicant anyway for a great [design pattern](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2008/03/the_ruby_mendicant_project.html) for right livelihood as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Though not completely ruby, you could use OpenOffice .odt to generate PDFs by combining serenity and docsplit.

http://github.com/kremso/serenity

http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/

Or you could use the clamsy gem which uses odt and cups-pdf to generate the PDF.

http://github.com/ngty/clamsy

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I agree with most other answers that [`prawn`](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) is the right choice because you need pixel-level control over the output.

For generating PDF reports with built-in (opinionated) table styling, headers, etc., you can use the [`report`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/report) gem - check out [Generate pdf from Rails 3 - what tool to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117884/generate-pdf-from-rails-3-what-tool-to-choose/15817893#15817893) for an example of how to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've used flying saucer for pdf generation from html. It's a java library but you can use the Ruby-Java Bridge gem to access it in your rails app. It's css 2.1 compliant and has a few additions from css3 to allow some extra control over paging. I'd recommend it as it doesn't require you to put 'pdf code' in your html, you can use the same views and partials to display to the browser as you do to generate pdfs.

Flying Saucer: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Ruby Java Bridge: http://rjb.rubyforge.org/

I use this module code to generate the pdfs

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rjb'

module Html2Pdf

  def self.included(controller)
      controller.send :helper_method, :create_pdf
  end

  def create_pdf(options = {})
      itext = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/html2pdf/jars/iText-2.0.8.jar"
      core_renderer = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/html2pdf/jars/core-renderer.jar"
      xerces = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/html2pdf/jars/xml-apis-xerces-2.9.1.jar" 
      joinchar = (RUBY_PLATFORM.include? 'mswin') ? ';' : ':'
          classpath = [itext, core_renderer, xerces].join(joinchar)
      Rjb::load(classpath, jvmargs=['-Djava.awt.headless=true'])
      if options[:htmlstring].nil?
      options[:layout] ||= false
          options[:template] ||= File.join(controller_path,action_name+".pdf.erb")
          html_string = render_to_string(:template => options[:template], :layout => options[:layout])
    else
          html_string = options[:htmlstring]
    end
    # Make all paths relative, on disk paths...
    html_string.gsub!(".com:/",".com/") # strip out bad attachment_fu URLs
    html_string.gsub!( /src=["']+([^:]+?)["']/i ) { |m| "src=\"file:///#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/" + $1 + '"' } # re-route absolute paths
    html_string.gsub!( /url\(["']+([^:]+?)["']/i ) { |m| "url\(\"file:///#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/" + $1 + '"' } # re-route absolute paths
    # Remove asset ids on images with a regex // tbh i can't remember what this line is for but i'm sure it did something awesome
    html_string.gsub!( /src=["'](\S+\?\d*)["']/i ) { |m| 'src="' + $1.split('?').first + '"' } 
    filename = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/"+options[:filename]+".pdf"
    fileOutputStream = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')
      iTextRenderer = Rjb::import('org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer')
      renderer = iTextRenderer.new
      renderer.setDocumentFromString(html_string)
      os = fileOutputStream.new(filename)
      renderer.layout()
      renderer.createPDF(os)
      os.close()
  end

end
```

Calling it with code like this:

```
def generate_pdf  
  htmlsrc = render_to_string(:partial => 'invoice', :layout => false)
  rnd = Time.now.to_s(:datentime).gsub!(/[\/ \.:]/,'')
  filename = "docstore/tmp_#{rnd}"
  create_pdf(:htmlstring => htmlsrc, :filename => filename)
  contents = open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/#{filename}.pdf", "rb") { |io| io.read }
  File.delete("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/#{filename}.pdf")
  respond_to do | wants |
    wants.html { render :text => contents, :content_type => 'application/pdf' }
  end    
end
```