# PDF generation with Prawn and Prawnto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn, jrubyonrails, prawnto

Is anyone using Prawn / Prawnto with Jruby on rails?  I installed prawn 0.5.01 and rails 2.3.2.  I just installed prawn and prawnto and started playing with the PDF generation capabilities.  I am concerned that the pranwto web site is no longer online - http://www.cracklabs.com/prawnto  Is this rails plugin dead?  Or has it moved somewhere? Based on other posts [Generate PDF from Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433136/generate-pdf-from-rails) these seem like the PDF gen tools of choice for Ruby and (J)Ruby on Rails.  Can someone with experience with PDF gen in RoR confirm that this is still the way to go?

(Note: I'm using Jruby on Rails, so if there is a better option or something in Java that I should be exploring further let me know... I googled [Flying Saucer Project](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) from this [post](http://bosmeeuw.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/jruby-on-rails-pdf-generation-and-flying-saucers/), which seemed interesting... thoughts on this project?)

Comment: I would highly recommend you look at the Flying Saucer Project to write an HTML/CSS to PDF converter in Java.  It's an outstanding project and you can achieve great results in a handful of lines.  Since you're using JRuby, it makes even more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prawnto plugin is  is up and alive on
[Github](http://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto/tree/master), albeit without much documentation.

I have built several Rails apps that put PDF generation front and center, and I can definitely attest that Prawn/Prawnto is the way to go. The DSL provided by Prawn is really elegant and pleasant to work with, and even though the library isn't as feature-packed as others, it handles most of what you will need out of the box without any pain at all.

I saw Gregory Brown (author of the Prawn library) give a talk about Ruby implementations, and he's a user of JRuby. I'd be surprised if you find any problems there, though I haven't personally used Prawn with JRuby.

The [Prawn Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/prawn-ruby) is relatively active and helpful, so you might want to check it out as well.

It also appears that the [Prawn website](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) is still available as well.

Answer (score 4):

We tried all of those solutions (prawn/prawnto, Prince, Ruport, and I think even PDF-writer) before running into the "[**Wicked PDF**](http://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/tree/master)" Rails plugin and [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/tree/master).

It's been a LIFE SAVER!

The plugin and utility combination use Webkit to generate PDF documents from your views. So you can reuse all your HTML, erb, haml, css and sass to create great looking PDFs without rewriting almost anything.

The utility (wkhtmltopdf) is Open Source and is available in source packages as well as binary packages for Linux, Windows and Mac. Of course, our sorry butts have to run Solaris, so I've been trying to compile the thing for a month now...arg. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Prawn has been moved to GitHub. 
You should be able to download the source there.

http://github.com/sandal/prawn/tree/master

Also - as of 10/08/2009, the latest changes to the library appear to have been on July 19, 2009. So it seems the library is alive.