# Generate PDF from rails in rest way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, pdf

I want to generate PDF in rails application. I had saw different options for doing this but 
I want all data needed for PDF should be collected in a format (mostly XML) such that it can be utilized by my rails application for generating the reports as well as be consumed by other applications( Web Service)
 The data I have use for generating PDf it comes from different object and basically it contains images and graphs. Data volume is also big

I want to generate PDF with proper style and layout. Can anybody suggest me the best option I can use in my rails application to achieve above problem

Comment: Anybody have any solutions for this problem?

Comment: According to [this post][1] you should look at Prawn or PDFKit


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117884/generate-pdf-from-rails-3-what-tool-to-choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using an online/cloud service is an option, you might want to look at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com).  It can generate PDFs using a rest interface and has at least one Ruby example.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Answer (score 2):

[Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) or [PDFKit](http://rubygems.org/gems/pdfkit) seem to be the two most popular right now. Each has their ups and downs depending on what you are trying to do and the styles they want to apply. For PDFKit here is an [article](http://metaskills.net/2011/03/20/pdfkit-overview-and-advanced-usage/) talking about how it integrates with Rails

Comment: Thanks Scott It's really helpful for me.