# how to generate pdf file using prawn in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Right now i am using rails 3.0.0 version.i already installed prawn gem.please tell me.how to generate pdf file in rails code and how to save that pdf file inside the public folder.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433136/generate-pdf-from-rails

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial?
http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn